# VS 2013 Rebuild does not get the latest dlls

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using VS2013 and my solution has a Web application. Lets call it MyWebApp.

MyWebApp references 2 class libraries(lets call them a.dll and b.dll) these class libraries have their own (C#) projects and are also part of this 
solution. Both of a.dll and b.dll are referenced by MyWebapp.

The problem is every time I REBUILD the solution, MyWebapp does not get latest version of a.dll and b.dll.

So I have to go to "a" project and "b" project bin folder and get the latest from there and copy it to MyWebapp bin folder.

If I delete a.dll and b.dll from the MyWebapp bin folder, then Rebuild  gets the latest.

So what is the best way to handle this situation(other than me use pre-compile to delete those files)

Do you see any issues if I just change the output folder of a project and b.project and set it to bin folder of MyWebapp?

Comment: Are you referencing the physical .dll files, or are you referencing the projects that build them?

Comment: I reference the dlls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reference the .dll files, then yes, you can get 'old' build files since it depends on the order that visual studio builds them that decides if your depending project is build first, or if it is the referenced project that is build first.

The solution is to reference the class library projects instead of the dll files. Then you also will have no trouble if you change the platform, or the solution configuration, or go from debug to release.

Check this Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26403061/261050

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are referencing these dlls as assembly reference and not project reference. Follow below steps to fix it.

1. Remove references of dlls in question from your project.
2. Right click on references of your project.
3. Select add references.
4. In reference manager select "Solution" tab.
5. Select entries named after a.dll and b.dll.
6. Build solution. Every time you do new build you should get latest of a.dll and b.dll